# Discrepancy between laplace and fourier transform of gaussian

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

The function in question is Exp[x^2/2] for x>0

Laplace transform should be the same as the fourier transform since the function is absolutely integrable.

[image]

Fourier:

[image]

They are indeed the same

[image]

Mathematica is able to inverse transform the expression with DawsonF, but for the other one it is wrong.

[image]